# filter product by name not working

Tags: filter, name

i have written custom code to display all product by their category id now i want to add name filter which searches and show name matching with product

1: my category code works fine 
2: when i add like filter to sort name i get null result please help me find out issue 
i had used **addAttributeToFilter** which does not seems working

```
$category_id = $_GET['category_id']; 
$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product



$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('id','name','url','small_image','price')); //add product attribute to be fetched

if($_GET['keyword']!=''){
    $needle= $_GET['keyword'];
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
        array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %')
    ));
}

$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if($_GET['keyword']!=''){
$needle= $_GET['keyword'];
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '% '.$needle.' %')
));
```

You need to remove the empty space in the '%' quotes.

```
if($_GET['keyword']!=''){
$needle= $_GET['keyword'];
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('name', array(
    array('like' => '%'.$needle.'%')
));
```